# HTML form File input is empty in Google Script - Web

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have created a web application in Google Script with a custom HTML form. The form looks like below:

```
<form id="msForm">
    .......
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="certificateFile" accept="application/pdf" required >
    .....
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS has the following

```
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".next").click(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="Submit") {
     google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(successFormSubmit)
      .withFailureHandler(failedFormSubmit)
      .processForm($(this).closest("form")[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

The google script in the Code.gs

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  console.log(formObject.certificateFile);
}
```

The log trace shows as empty in the execution's log, when I select a file and then click the submit button.

```
{}
```

**---- Edit to have more details ----**

The form is having 4 file upload field including the given above and all are getting empty at server side.

The form was working fine and I added the validation later. Now the form is not submitting the file contents even they are shown at client side.

The form submitting code is :

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFormSubmit).withFailureHandler(failedFormSubmit).processForm(document.getElementById("msForm"));
```

**Code.gs**

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  console.log(formObject.certificateFile);
}
```

Further more, I added [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en) and removed as it was giving errors and not working properly.

**--- Edit 02 ---**

I have found the root cause for the problem. This happens when there are more than one `file input` field in the html form. Can anyone tell me to over come this? Is it with default GCP project settings?

**--- Edit 03 ---**
This issue has been fixed by Google.[enter link description here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212826471)

Comment: This is maybe because you're not using FileReader object, you need to get the content of the file before sending it to app-script to process it.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with this bug in Apps Script: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155109626?pli=1

Comment: Can you share more details on the full code?

Comment: About `I have created a web application in Google Script with a custom HTML form.`, in the current stage, I think that when your HTML & Javascript is run with Web Apps instead of the sidebar and dialog on Google Docs, `formObject.certificateFile` has the value which is not empty. In this case, I thought that it is required to know your actual situation for replicating your issue. So, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, that bug is fixed and closed.

Comment: @Kos In the current stage, the bug was resolved for only Web Apps. For the sidebar and dialog, I confirmed that the bug is not resolved. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/09/fixed-google-apps-script-web-app-html-form-file-input-fields-not-in-blob-compatible-format/) But, in the case of OP's situation, when the sidebar or dialog was used, I thought that `formObject.certificateFile` might return `undefined` instead of `{}`. So I asked the detailed information.

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable comments. The code was working without any errors few days before I add the `jQuery` validation. @vector I am not using any file reader to read the file content so using html file input field.

Comment: Can you share how did you have it before and after the changes made?

Comment: @Kessy I have found the root cause for the problem. It happens if there are more than one file input field. Anyone here aware of it?

Comment: What are the value of the name property of each file input? PS. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported and now it is fixed by the Google.

You can find more details [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212826471).